# connecting to metamask wallet in android app project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, blockchain, metamask

Is there any way to connect an Android app written in Java or Kotlin to a MetaMask wallet? I think the MetaMask mobile SDK on GitHub is just for React Mative projects.

Answer (score 2):

These kotlin libraries by walletConnect and trustwallet might be helpful to you :

- https://github.com/WalletConnect/kotlin-walletconnect-lib
- https://github.com/trustwallet/wallet-connect-kotlin

Do check these demo apps:

- https://github.com/WalletConnect/kotlin-walletconnect-lib/blob/master/sample/app/src/main/java/io/walletconnect/example/MainActivity.kt
- https://github.com/trustwallet/wallet-connect-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/trustwallet/walletconnect/sample/MainActivity.kt

Code sample:

```kotlin
val peerMeta = WCPeerMeta(name = "App name", url = "https://website.com")
val string = "wc:..."
val session = WCSession.from(string) ?: throw InvalidSessionError // invalid session
// handle session
wcClient.connect(wcSession, peerMeta)

val wcClient = WCClient(GsonBuilder(), okHttpClient)

wcClient.onDisconnect = { _, _ -> 
    onDisconnect() 
}

wcClient.onSessionRequest = { _, peer -> 
    // ask for user consent
}

wcClient.onDisconnect = { _, _ -> 
    // handle disconnect
}
wcClient.onFailure = { t -> 
    // handle failure
}
wcClient.onGetAccounts = { id -> 
    // handle get_accounts
}

wcClient.onEthSign = { id, message -> 
    // handle eth_sign, personal_sign, eth_signTypedData
}
wcClient.onEthSignTransaction = { id, transaction -> 
    // handle eth_signTransaction
}
wcClient.onEthSendTransaction = { id, transaction -> 
    // handle eth_sendTransaction
}

wcClient.onSignTransaction = { id, transaction -> 
    // handle bnb_sign
}
```

Comment: how to restrict wallet connect v1 to just meta mask